# Failed javadoc downloads with sbteclipse when using with-source=true

Tags: playframework, sbt, sbteclipse

When I invoke `sbt` and type `eclipse with-source=true`, I get a bunch of failed javadoc downloads:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: eu.medsea.mimeutil#mime-util;2.1.3!mime-util.jar(src)
[warn]  :: eu.medsea.mimeutil#mime-util;2.1.3!mime-util.jar(doc)
[warn]  :: com.typesafe#config;0.3.1!config.jar(doc)
[warn]  :: com.typesafe#config;0.3.1!config.jar(src)
[warn]  :: commons-httpclient#commons-httpclient;3.1!commons-httpclient.jar(doc)
[warn]  :: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1!commons-logging.jar(src)
[warn]  :: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1!commons-logging.jar(doc)
[warn]  :: commons-io#commons-io;1.4!commons-io.jar(src)
[warn]  :: commons-io#commons-io;1.4!commons-io.jar(doc)
[warn]  :: org.codehaus.woodstox#wstx-asl;3.2.7!wstx-asl.jar(doc)
[warn]  :: io.netty#netty;3.4.4.Final!netty.jar(doc)
[warn]  :: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.3!httpclient.jar(doc)
[warn]  :: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.2!httpcore.jar(doc)
[warn]  :: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6!commons-codec.jar(doc)
[warn]  :: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6!commons-codec.jar(src)
[warn]  :: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpmime;4.2.3!httpmime.jar(doc)
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

It looks like the javadoc jar files are simply missing from both the public Maven repository, and Sonatype's repository.

Why are so many javadoc files missing for these reasonably popular packages?

What repository is guaranteed to have a lot of these javadoc packages?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313123/how-to-skip-javadoc-download-with-sbt

Answer (score 0):

From within the play console, type "update-classifiers" to retrieve
the sources and javadoc, or "eclipsify with-source=true" to include
them in the generated eclipse project.
(excluding the quotes)

its mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17127380)