# SBT sources in IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm using `*.scala` files in the `project` folder for configuring my SBT project. I'm using IDEA12 with the Scala Plugin and `sbt-idea` for generating the project. After calling `gen-idea` in the SBT shell, everything works fine except for one thing. When I click `go to declaration` on some method in my project code, IDEA shows me how it is implemented (redirects me to the library sources). But when I'm trying to "inspect" SBT's internal sources it shows me something like this:

`def settings: Seq[Setting[_]] = { /** compiled code **/ }`

How can I attach SBT sources to my IDEA project?

I'm using SBT `0.12.3`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In SBT there are two command which may interest you:

`update-classifiers` - will download all sources and documentation for all libs in your project 
`update-sbt-classifiers` - downloads sbt sources and docs

This will download all the sources you need. To make an IDEA project with them just call `gen-idea sbt-classifiers`.

If you don't want to call each time this commands for re-generating you project, you should add something like this to your *build.sbt*: `addCommandAlias("make-idea", ";update-classifiers; update-sbt-classifiers; gen-idea sbt-classifiers")`.

Comment: just 'gen-idea sbt-classifiers' should be enough

Comment: It also works for Play! project. Type same commands in Play console:  
update-sbt-classifiers ..and then gen-idea sbt-classifiers

Comment: You losing first semicolon
`addCommandAlias("make-idea", ";update-classifiers; update-sbt-classifiers; gen-idea sbt-classifiers")`

Comment: When I do that I get `[error] Not a valid command: sbt-classifiers` please help

Comment: you need to have `sbt-idea` added to your plugins, @samthebest: `addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.6.0")`

Comment: None of the answers here work with sbt 1.x or with 2022.2 IntellilJ – it still can't find SBT sources.

Answer (score 4):

As of sbt version 1.2.8, the command is changed to:
`sbt updateClassifiers` - to download all sources and docs
`sbt updateSbtClassifiers` - to download sbt sources and docs.