# How to make sbt download its own sources/javadoc?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I know that I can download the sources/java-doc for my dependencies using the `update-classifiers` task.

But it would also be interesting to be able to download the sbt sources/java-doc, as Intellij is not showing me any kind of documentation for sbt-related stuff. I've already checked on their website and they seem to only provide the binaries. I would like to avoid having to download their github project, if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SBT sources in IDEA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127367/sbt-sources-in-idea)

Comment: Suppose you meant `update-classifiers`