# How to skip javadoc dependency download with sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, javadoc

1) Javadoc artifacts tend to take too much space and time to download.
For example, `scala-library-2.10.2-sources.jar` is 1 Mb, but `scala-library-2.10.2-javadoc.jar` is 34 Mb.

2) Javadoc is mostly not needed at all. As modern IDEs can fetch all info from sources.

So I wanted to find a way to alter sbt settings to completely disable javadoc download among third-party library dependencies.

Comment: If your #2 is really true, perhaps you could send a message to sbt-dev proposing that it be off by default?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea/issues/225#issuecomment-19150022 kindly gives the answer:

> The javadoc is typically much more bulky and less useful than the
>   sources. I have at least turned off downloading javadocs by putting
>   this setting in ~/.sbt/build.sbt:

```
transitiveClassifiers in Global := Seq(Artifact.SourceClassifier)
```

See also [What is a classifier in SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571534/what-is-a-classifier-in-sbt).

Note that `~/.sbt/build.sbt` on Linux corresponds to `%USERPROFILE%\.sbt\build.sbt` on Windows.